# SQL Server - Selecting columns with two matching other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like so:

```
columna int
columnb int
```

Some sample data:

```
columna columnb
   1       1
   1       2
   1       3
   2       1
   2       2
   2       4
   3       1
   3       3
   3       7
   4       3
   5       2
   5       3
```

I want to select `columna` where the same value for `columna` has both 1 and 3 in `columnb`.

So my results for the sample above should be:

```
1
3
```

I have tried a number of things but can't get what I want, can somebody help me out here.

Comment: Can you be please more specific on what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055(v=sql.120).aspx) operator, it returns distinct rows that are output by both input queries.

So first query should be values of `columna` from records having `columnb = 1`, second one - values of `columna` from records having `columnb = 3` and then intersect results of both queries.

```
select columna
from your_table 
where columnb = 1

intersect

select columna
from your_table
where columnb = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.columnA) 
FROM Table_Name t1
INNER JOIN Table_Name t2 ON t1.columnA = t2.columnB
```